# Python Mutliprocessing/Sockets - Bad File Descriptor

Tags: python, sockets, concurrency, process, concurrent-programming

I am writing a server in Python which the client will send the command (via command line arg) "BYE". The connection between the client/server should be terminated at this time. (I figured that socket.close() would terminate the connection but I am not completely sure if that is correct)

I wrote the adapted an echo server where clientsocket.close() was at the end of the server iteration. I want this to occur only if BYE is recieved.

I am not sure if the structure of my server program is causing the issue (I am not using getopt yet - as I still need to figure it out)

The server:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import socket
import os

def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    print "Accepted connection from: ", clientaddr
    while 1:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        if data:
            if data == "BYE":
                print "recvd BYE"
                clientsocket.send("BYE")
                clientsocket.close()
#                p.join()
            elif data == "DIR":
                print "recvd DIR"
                DIR = os.getcwd()
                clientsocket.send(DIR)

            print "data recieved:"
            print data
            msg = "You sent me: %s" % data
            clientsocket.send(msg)
            clientsocket.close()
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":

    TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 5004
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    print 'socket()'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print 'bind()'
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

#    f = open('recv.txt', 'wb')

    print 'listen()'
    s.listen(5)

    workerProcesses =[]

    while 1:
        print "Server is listening for connections\n"
        clientsocket, clientaddr = s.accept()
        p = Process(target=handler, args = (clientsocket, clientaddr))
        p.start()
#        p.join()
        workerProcesses.append(p)

    serversocket.close()
```

When I put my clientsocket.close() in the if "BYE" statement, I get the error: bad socket descriptor. The output of the server is:

```
data recieved:
BYE
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "pyServ.py", line 26, in handler
    clientsocket.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 167, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any ides on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your handler() function you have this:

```
       if data == "BYE":
            print "recvd BYE"
            clientsocket.send("BYE")
            clientsocket.close()
            #p.join()
        elif data == "DIR":
            print "recvd DIR"
            DIR = os.getcwd()
            clientsocket.send(DIR)

        print "data recieved:"
        print data
        msg = "You sent me: %s" % data
        clientsocket.send(msg)
        clientsocket.close()
        return
```

if `data == "BYE"` then you send "BYE" and close your socket... then you print "data recieved" (typo) :)

and then you call `close()` inside the `if` statement. Once outside the `if` statement, you try to `send()` data again on that socket you just closed. Once you close the socket, the file handle is no longer valid. You need to modify your code so that you do not send on a closed socket... there are two obvious ways that I see.

**Should be**

```
        if data == "BYE":
            print "recvd BYE"
            clientsocket.send("BYE")
            clientsocket.close()
            #p.join()
        elif data == "DIR":
            print "recvd DIR"
            DIR = os.getcwd()
            clientsocket.send(DIR)

        print "data recieved:"
        print data
        return
```

**OR**

Remove the call to clientsocket.close() inside your `if` statement

Comment: Thank you very much, in order to achieve my goal (end the socket on "BYE") I omitted the second send() and close() calls like in your first example and it worked exactly as I was hoping.